problem with some apps in ubuntu 24.04
I'm encountering issues with both VSCode and Azure Data Studio on Ubuntu 24.04. Whenever I launch the applications, they crash after a few seconds. I've attempted to troubleshoot and search for solutions, but haven't been able to find any. Has anyone else experienced similar problems?

Edit your post to add information on how these applications were installed. I presume using the App store? Also add system information: if this is not a general issue, specifics of your hardware may be the issue. A starting defect in some of your hardware components (e.g. graphics card) also cannot be excluded if it only happens on a specific computer.

Try this https://askubuntu.com/a/1511655/124466
